# When I set onTouchListener for a RecyclerView and set onClickListener for a childView of RecyclerView,

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

First I set `onTouchListener` for the `recyclerView`.

```
recyclerview.setOnTouchListener(this);
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    System.out.println("action_down");
                    if (layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
                        GridLayoutManager g = ((GridLayoutManager) layoutManager);
                        System.out.println("findFirstVisibleItemPosition = " + g.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
                        if (g.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                            isTop = true;
                            startY = (int) event.getY();
                        }
                    } else if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
                        LinearLayoutManager l = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
                        System.out.println("findFirstVisibleItemPosition = " + l.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
                        if (l.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                            isTop = true;
                            startY = (int) event.getY();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    System.out.println("action_move");
                }
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    System.out.println("action_up");
                    if (state == RELEASE) {
                        state = REFRESHING;
                        refreshState();
                        listener.onRefreshing();
                    } else if (state == PULL) {
                        state = NORMAL;
                        isTop = false;
                        resetRefresh(paddingBottom, -headerRefreshHeight, 400);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Second i set `onClickListener()` for a `childView` of the `RecyclerView` in Adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int pos = position;
        if (onItemClickListener != null) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, pos);
                }
            });
        }

        if (onItemLongClickListener != null) {
            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    return onItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClickListener(v, position);
                }
            });
        }
        convert(holder, data.get(position));
    }
```

finally in `onTouch()` function ,there is no action_down `MotionEvent` any more.
I cant figure it out. Anyone knows about it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What did you want to achieve?

Comment: a RecyclerView's pull to refresh.when i set onClickListener for a childView of the recyclerView and then I did recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(),in onTouch method ,action_down MotionEvent likely be comsumed.forgive me for my bad english.I'm a foreigner.sorry for that.i hope you understand what i said.

Comment: Did you mean, when you clicked the item in RecyclerView nothing happened? Please see this: https://gist.github.com/riyazMuhammad/1c7b1f9fa3065aa5a46f

Comment: Have you ever met this situation where you are going to use RecyclerView in your project and you want to set onTouchListener for RecyclerView and onClickListener() for RecyclerView 's itemView at the same time.When i dont set onClickListener() for RecyclerView's itemView ,everything is ok.But when i set onClickListerer() for RecyclerView's itemView,problems arise.in onTouch method,no MotionEvent.ACTOIN_DOWN.I likely said not enough clearly.Thanks for your patience!!!

Comment: I guess the https://gist.github.com/riyazMuhammad/1c7b1f9fa3065aa5a46f can help you. I have met kind of similar situation where clicking a button within item of RecyclerView  and scrolling the RecyclerView.